# Ionic factory undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Newbie in Ionic and Angular.

I am trying to develop a test app and trying to use the factory function.
I did the design from Ionic Creator and trying to add my coding in to it.

Below is my controller file.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, awesomeFactory) {
        $scope.aa = awesomeFactory.GetUser();
    }])

.controller('mainPageCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('historyCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('firstrunCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('resultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('doctorCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('bookingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])

.controller('appointmentCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
}])
```

Below is my file that has the factory.

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('BlankFactory', [function(){

}])

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}]


.factory('awesomeFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        GetUser: function() {
              return $http.get("http addy return json object").then(function(response) {
                    //Process Stuff Here
                    return response;
              });
        },
    }
})

);
```

I am getting 2 errors.
1. Error: awesomeFactory is undefined.
2. TypeError: (intermediate value).factory is not a function[Learn More]

I just don't know what I am doing wrong. Probably something small.
But any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because here in this code

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, awesomeFactory) {
        $scope.aa = awesomeFactory.GetUser();
    }])
```

First you will have to do factory `injection` then try to create its instance

Try this

```
.controller('loadingCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','awesomeFactory',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, awesomeFactory) {
        $scope.aa = awesomeFactory.GetUser();
    }])
```

Comment: Hi, it's returning an Unknown provider error.It says : Unknown provider : awesomeFactoryProvider <- awesomeFactory <- loadingCtrl

Comment: only one error now?? make sure you have referenced js file in your index.html

Comment: Yes only one error now. And yes reference is there.

Comment: Firgured it out. The app.js was missing 'app.factories' apparently.